# Python, storing user input in an array, then printing them out inside a poem

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write a simple madlib for my programming class, and struggling for the past two days.

I want to prompt the user to enter two colors, then store them in an array inside a function.

I want to create another function where I prompt the user to enter two verbs and store them in an array.

Finally, I want to call these two functions in my main function where I insert the user inputs into a poem.

for example:

```
def main():   
    print("Roses are", colors[],".")   
    print("Violet are",color[],".")   
    print("The weather may", verb[],".")   
    print("But I will always", verb[],"you.") 
main()
```

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: What is `colors[]` and `color[]` in your program?

Comment: @Anurag A S I meant just color[ ]. color[ ] is the array or list I'm trying to write to store user input, when I prompt the user to enter two colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you change your code to this:

```
color = []
verb = []
def getcolors():
    color.append(input("enter a color"))
    color.append(input("enter a color"))

def getverbs():
    verb.append(input("enter a verb"))
    verb.append(input("enter a verb"))

def main():
    print("Roses are" + color[0] + ".")
    print("Violet are" +color[1] +".")
    print("The weather may", verb[0] +".")
    print("But I will always", verb[1] +"you.")

getverbs()
getcolors()
main()
```

Like he said, look at tutorials on youtube and on the web

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is something like this:

```
colors = []
verbs = []
def get_colors(colors_list):
    for i in range(2):
        color = input('Enter a color: ')
        colors_list.append(color)


def get_verbs(verbs_list):
    for i in range(2):
        verb = input('Enter a verb: ')
        verbs_list.append(verb)


def poem(colors_list, verbs_list):
    print("Roses are", colors_list[0],".")   
    print("Violet are",colors_list[1],".")   
    print("The weather may", verbs_list[0],".")   
    print("But I will always", verbs_list[1],"you.") 


get_colors(colors)
get_verbs(verbs)
poem(colors, verbs)
```

**An advice:** Please read a lot for programming fundamentals. Read how to define functions in Python, how to enter or get data from keyboard inputs and how manage lists. Look for some classes in Youtube to understand in a better way, don't be afraid for new things.

Comment: Thank you so much Geancarlo! I appreciate the advice.